# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable, scores.sort()

Tags: sorting, ipython

```
scores.append((item, score))
output_file.write(scores.sort()[:20] + '\n')
```

I need to sort scores and write top 20 scores in a file. Above is my code and I end up with the TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally the exception should be

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

But however, you can not run this:

```
scores.sort()[:20]
```

That's simply because `list.sort()` modifies the list in-place and does not return anything (that means it implicitly returns `None`).

So you either have to place the `scores.sort()` in a separate statement before the slicing operation...

```
scores.append((item, score))
scores.sort()
output_file.write(scores[:20] + '\n')
```

... or you use the built-in method `sorted(...)` that does not modify the original list but returns a sorted copy.

```
scores.append((item, score))
output_file.write(sorted(scores)[:20] + '\n')
```

You should chose the *first option* if you want to access the *sorted* list again later, but you must chose the *second option* if you want to access the *unsorted* list again later. In case you won't need the list any more at all, you can chose any option.

Comment: Instead of writing "Thank you" comments, please accept this answer by clicking the grey tick button on the left side if it helped you. Also read the [tour] page and check out the [help] to learn about how this site works.

Answer (score 2):

The `sort()` list method orders the given list. It *does not return a new list*. This is key to understand the error you're having.

The official [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) says:

> This method modifies the sequence in place for economy of space when
> sorting a large sequence. To remind users that it operates by side
> effect, **it does not return the sorted sequence**.

If you apply the `sort()` method and print it, it will return `None` and not the sorted list:

```
lst = [1,4,2,5]
print(lst.sort())
> None
```

When you do `scores.sort()[:20]` you're trying to get items from a list by indexing, also referred as slicing. The thing is, as I showed above, that that expression returns `None`, which can't be accesed by indexing.

That's why you get the error message:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

It's just saying that `NoneType` object can't be indexed. What you tried to do is like doing:

```
None[:20]
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Which you can't, because *'NoneType' object is not subscriptable*.

---

If you need a new list, you have to use the `sorted()` [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted).
This function (and not a method) it's general. It's not for lists alone, it builds a new sorted list from an iterable (like lists, strings, tuples). Although it does return a list.

`sorted()` doesn't modify the original iterable. It creates a new object: a sorted list.

---

Which objects are subscriptable in Python? Those who implement the `__getitem__` and/or `__setitem__` dunder methods.

With `__getitem__`you can get a value, like `list[0]` returning the first value of a list.
With `__setitem__`you set a value, like `list[0]=1`.